# Android fragment load default images from drawable if Glide failed to connect to a remote server

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

i am trying to load some default picture from drawable in case Glide can't connect to a server and fetch images.
i am using a fragment with an adapter.

here is my fragment :

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


private ArrayList<Image> images;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private GalleryAdapter mAdapter;
protected RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TextView titreDemo;

....
....
....

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentPhotoInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentPhotoInteraction(Uri uri);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    images = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getContext(), images);
    titreDemo = getView().findViewById(R.id.titre_demo);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new GalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getContext(), recyclerView, new GalleryAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("images", images);
            bundle.putInt("position", position);

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            SlideshowDialogFragment newFragment = SlideshowDialogFragment.newInstance();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            newFragment.show(ft, "slideshow");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    fetchImages();

}


private void fetchImages() {

    pDialog.setMessage(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.loading) + " ...");
    pDialog.show();

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            pDialog.hide();

            images.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Image image = new Image();


                    JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
                    image.setSmall(url.getString("small"));
                    image.setMedium(url.getString("medium"));
                    image.setLarge(url.getString("large"));
                    image.setTag(url.getString("tag"));

                    if(getArguments() != null && getArguments().getString(DATA_RECEIVE) != null && !getArguments().getString(DATA_RECEIVE).isEmpty()){
                        if(getArguments().getString(DATA_RECEIVE).equals(image.getTag())) {
                            images.add(image);
                        }
                    }else{
                        images.add(image);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(images != null && !images.isEmpty()) {
                if(getArguments() != null && getArguments().getString(DATA_TITRE) != null) {
                    titreDemo.setText(getArguments().getString(DATA_TITRE));
                }
            }else{
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.photo_non_dispo))
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
}
```

and here is my adapter :

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Image> images;
private Context mContext;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView thumbnail;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }
}


public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<Image> images) {
    mContext = context;
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Image image = images.get(position);
    if(image != null && image.getMedium() != null) {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium()).load(image.getLarge()).thumbnail(0.5f).transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()).apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).dontAnimate().centerCrop().dontTransform()).into(holder.thumbnail);
    }else{
        Log.e("gallerie adapter", "inside onBindViewHolder");
        Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.building).load(R.drawable.building).thumbnail(0.5f).transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()).apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).dontAnimate().centerCrop().dontTransform()).into(holder.thumbnail);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
}
```

how can i display some picture from my drawables in case loading from remote server failed ?
as you can see i called `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onErrorResponse` to get in the adapter , but it's not working.
what is best way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Use ".error(YourImageFromDrawable)"

```
Drawable someImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.someImage);

Glide.with(getActivity())
            .load(uri)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(someImage).into(target);
```

This will load just in case some Error Occured Upon fetching your ImageUrl
Hope this helps :)

Comment: The problem is that I want show default images (in case of error) in recyclerView , so I must go through the adapter.

Comment: then you can put the code within the adapter. Works for me when I load thumbnails for my Phone Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

you can load placeholder image until the image is not loaded from server and error image when an error occur loading image.

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(url)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.error))
            .into(imageview);
```